# Android random string generator

Tags: android

I have a problem.
I want to draw a random String something like this aXcFg3s2.
What i doing bad ?
How change my `random()`

```
private String random;
private String charsEntered;
private EditText et;
private Button ok;
CaptchaInterface.OnCorrectListener mCorrectListener;

public void setOnCorrectListener(CaptchaInterface.OnCorrectListener listener) {
    mCorrectListener = listener;
}

public TextCaptcha(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}

public static String random() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    String x = (String) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
    return x;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    random = random();
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    display.setText("Random Number: " + random); // Show the random number
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumbers);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        charsEntered = et.getText().toString();
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), "Bla bla bla",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (random == charsEntered) {
        Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), "Good!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), "Bad!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited to add the code. Simply paste your code and then highlight it and click the code formatting editor button or ctrl + k (cmd + k on mac)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

You cannot cast from an int to a string. Cast it to a char instead. This however will only give you a single char so instead you could generate a random number for the length of your string. Then run a for loop to generate random chars. You can define a StringBuilder as well and add the chars to that, then get your random string using the `toString()` method

example:

```
public static String random() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    StringBuilder randomStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int randomLength = generator.nextInt(MAX_LENGTH);
    char tempChar;
    for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++){
        tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
        randomStringBuilder.append(tempChar);
    }
    return randomStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Also, you should use `random.compareTo()` rather than ==

Comment: randomLength may be 0 then return will be "" !!  so, `if(randomLength == 0) randomLength = 10 ;` Remember:   `public int nextInt (int n)` Returns a pseudo-random uniformly distributed int in the half-open range [0, n)

Comment: You CAN cast an int to a String. String.valueOf(generator.nextInt(96) +31);

Answer (score 82):

the problem is that you've handled only a single character instead of using a loop.

you can create an array of characters which has all of the characters that you wish to allow to be in the random string , then in a loop take a random position from the array and add append it to a stringBuilder . in the end , convert the stringBuilder to a string.

---

EDIT:
here's the simple algorithm i've suggested:

```
private static final String ALLOWED_CHARACTERS ="0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

private static String getRandomString(final int sizeOfRandomString)
  {
  final Random random=new Random();
  final StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(sizeOfRandomString);
  for(int i=0;i<sizeOfRandomString;++i)
    sb.append(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.charAt(random.nextInt(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.length())));
  return sb.toString();
  }
```

and on Kotlin:

```
companion object {
    private val ALLOWED_CHARACTERS = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
}

private fun getRandomString(sizeOfRandomString: Int): String {
    val random = Random()
    val sb = StringBuilder(sizeOfRandomString)
    for (i in 0 until sizeOfRandomString)
        sb.append(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS[random.nextInt(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.length)])
    return sb.toString()
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, but not his issue. You're right that his "algorithm", if it can even be called that, is terrible, but his problem (though he posted no error) is that his app will not compile as it stands right now bc you cannot cast an int to a String.

Comment: Ok I'll do an array of letters of the alphabet and numbers. and then draw such as 10 characters?

Comment: see my updated answer . of course ,you can create other algorithms . i just think it's a very simple one which is also easy to understand.

Comment: thats what i need thank you, i will use this while activation process.

Answer (score 56):

You need to import UUID.
Here is the code

```
import java.util.UUID;

id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: How to extract only first 7 characters from it?

Comment: @VVB - just use method String.substring: String mySubstring = id.substring(0, 7);

Comment: its better and more useful code , its standard code that other apps like OneSignal use it

Comment: This is the most simple answer that I have found. I used `String passw = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,5);` to generate a random password

Answer (score 12):

this is how i generate my random strings with desired characters and desired length

```
          char[] chars1 = "ABCDEF012GHIJKL345MNOPQR678STUVWXYZ9".toCharArray();
                                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                                Random random1 = new Random();
                                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                                {
                                    char c1 = chars1[random1.nextInt(chars1.length)];
                                    sb1.append(c1);
                                }
                                String random_string = sb1.toString();
```

Comment: I like this approach since you can decide what characters are valid in the random string :-)

Answer (score 2):

This function run in kotlin ->

```
fun randomString(stringLength: Int): String {
    val list = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray()
    var randomS = ""
    for (i in 1..stringLength) {
        randomS += list[getRandomNumber(0, list.size - 1)]
    }
    return randomS
}

fun getRandomNumber(min: Int, max: Int): Int {
   return Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min
}
```

Or you can use my library
https://github.com/Aryan-mor/Utils-Library

Comment: Please Remove the Construction Invocation from the Random class. because you cannot an instance of an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following method to generate random String with 5 character and it will return arrayList of random String

```
public ArrayList<String> generateRandomString() {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String str = "";

    String randomLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String randomLetterSmall = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
        str = String.valueOf(randomLetters.charAt(rnd.nextInt(randomLetters.length())));

        str += String.valueOf(randomLetterSmall.charAt(rnd.nextInt(randomLetters.length())));
        str += String.valueOf(randomLetterSmall.charAt(rnd.nextInt(randomLetters.length())));
        str += String.valueOf(randomLetterSmall.charAt(rnd.nextInt(randomLetters.length())));
        str += String.valueOf(randomLetterSmall.charAt(rnd.nextInt(randomLetters.length())));

        //Copy above line to increase character of the String
        list.add(str);
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private fun getRandomHexString(numchars: Int): String? {
    val r = Random()
    val sb = StringBuffer()
    while (sb.length < numchars) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(r.nextInt()))
    }
    return sb.toString().substring(0, numchars)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an int to a String. Try:

```
 Random generator = new Random();
 String x = String.valueOf (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
```

Comment: It's ok there is no error, but bad draws. I think I'll make these arraysbut how they draw from the example of 10 characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
final  String[] Textlist = { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3"};

TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
```

`Random random = new Random();`

`String randomText = TextList[random.nextInt(TextList.length)];`

```
yourTextView.setText(randomText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick one liner using the `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils` package.

```
String randonString = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(16);
```

Requires the library dependency in the gradle build file:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert current time (in millis) to string such as

```
import java.util.Calendar;

String newRandomId = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

Or

String newRandomId = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "";

//Eg: output: "1602791949543"
```